# How to automatically reload the ajax/jQuery table data after a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have created a jQuery/ajax API call function to read the JSON data and insert it into the HTML table and it works fine, But I want to auto-reload the table data after 5Sec when a button is clicked.

I tried some codes to make it work. How can I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://mydevtest.in/wp-json/pmprocurrencies/v1/all", function(data){
            var currency_Data = '';
            
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                currency_Data += '<tr>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.country_alpha + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_code + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_sign + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_rate + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td><button type="submit" id="delBtn" value="' + value.id + '">x</button></td>';
                currency_Data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#currency_tables").append(currency_Data);
            // Reload the table data on "#addcr" button click. 
            $("#addcr").on("click", function(){
                $("#currency_tables").load(location.href + " #currency_tables");
            });
            
        });
  
    });
```

Comment: "... after 5 seconds when a button is clicked" is a logically conflicting criterion. Do you mean that the data should refresh once 5 seconds _after_ a button is clicked?

Comment: @isherwood Yeah, when a specific button is clicked then it should only reload/refresh the api data which displays in the table. I don't wanna run/refresh every x second. Just once when button is clicked.

Comment: @isherwood To trigger the refresh, I can use setTimeOut function but the problem is, after the function trigger, data doesn't display in table. So I wanted to know where exactly I am making mistake and how we can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to find the solution myself, below is the working code, But I think it's not the professional solution to repeat the same function to achieve the result. If anyone has any better idea, Please suggest.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://mydevtest.in/wp-json/pmprocurrencies/v1/all", function(data){
            var currency_Data = '';
            
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                currency_Data += '<tr>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.country_alpha + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_code + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_sign + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_rate + '</td>';
                currency_Data += '<td><button type="submit" id="delBtn" value="' + value.id + '">x</button></td>';
                currency_Data += '</tr>';
            });
            $("#currency_tables").html(currency_Data);
            // Reload the table data on "#addcr" button click. 
            
            
        });

        $("#addcr").on("click", function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://mydevtest.in/wp-json/pmprocurrencies/v1/all", function(data){
                var currency_Data = '';
                
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    currency_Data += '<tr>';
                    currency_Data += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                    currency_Data += '<td>' + value.country_alpha + '</td>';
                    currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_code + '</td>';
                    currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_sign + '</td>';
                    currency_Data += '<td>' + value.currency_rate + '</td>';
                    currency_Data += '<td><button type="submit" id="delBtn" value="' + value.id + '">x</button></td>';
                    currency_Data += '</tr>';
                });
                $("#currency_tables").replaceWith(currency_Data);
                // Reload the table data on "#addcr" button click. 
            });
            }, 4000)
        });
  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout(function,milliseconds)` for this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: Hi Rishab, I tried, but the problem is after clicking the button and when timer ends then it tries to refresh but it doesn't load the data in the table. and thats where i am stuck

Comment: I am not sure, maybe you have to try async function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function